# Cannot hide default action bar when scrolling down

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I hide the default action bar when scrolling down my recyclerview?
Do I need to create in my XML a new action bar? I want it to dissapear whenever the user scrolls down and then it to reapear when the user scrolls up again. This is a common thing in android apps.
Currently my XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewObjectives"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabNewObjective"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_new_objective"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where is the toolbar?

Comment: I said that in the question. It is in the AppTheme, do I need to create one myself?

Comment: What does it mean "*It is in AppTheme*"? Are you using a Toolbar or a ActionBar ?

Comment: ActionBar* ups, my bad

Comment: can't see any toolbar/action bar in here

Comment: you wouldn't see an action bar in there if it's a default one.

Comment: Use a `Toolbar` and a `CoordinatorLayout` include the layout reported in the question and apply the `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` in the include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a coordinator layout to do what you want.  You also need to create a layout for the appbar in your layout so the coordinator layout can control it.
It's explained better here:  https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html
Note:  you also are supposed to be using a coordinator layout if you have a floating action button.  If you don't then it can not dynamically respond to events such as the keyboard showing or a snackbar.

Comment: So everytime one uses the FAB it is good practice to use CoordinatorLayout?

Comment: it's not strictly necessary but it won't do some of the animations without it.